# Accessing the socket that emitted a message in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a class named GameServer which has methods for handling various socket.io messages. Here is a brief example:

```
var GameServer = function(app, io) {
  this.app = app;
  this.io = io;
  this.io.on('connection', this.handleConnect.bind(this));
};

GameServer.prototype.handleConnect = function(socket) {
  socket.on('receive_a_message', this.handleMessage.bind(this));
};

GameServer.prototype.handleMessage = function(message) {
  this.app.doSomethingWithMessage(message);
  // here is where I want to reply/emit to the socket that sent me the message
};
```

Unfortunately, because I need to bind() my socket.io callback methods in order to access other class properties (in the example above, I need to access this.app to run doSomethingWithMessage), I am in a different context.

Is there a way for me to bind my socket.io callbacks to my GameServer class and still access the socket that sent my messages? Can anyone see a work around to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already passing the context in a bind. You can pass the socket as part of the bind as well.

```
var GameServer = function(app, io) {
  this.app = app;
  this.io = io;
  this.io.on('connection', this.handleConnect.bind(this));
};

GameServer.prototype.handleConnect = function(socket) {
  socket.on('receive_a_message', this.handleMessage.bind(this, socket));
};

GameServer.prototype.handleMessage = function(socket, message) {
  this.app.doSomethingWithMessage(message);
  socket.emit('a reply');
};
```

Comment: I hadn't heard of the additional arguments bind takes. That is an incredibly helpful solution.